# Why doesn't CSS work when I deploy the Next.js sample project in production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, next.js

I'm currently developing an application using `Next.js` and `Nginx` in `Docker`.

`CSS` doesn't work after I `build` a project and check the display in the browser like below.

How could I resolve this problem?

---

The process and code to deploy are as follows：

1.Make a next project

```
$ npx create-next-app@latest --use-npm next-nginx-docker
```

2.Make a Dockerfile.prod

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.19-alpine AS server

COPY ./etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=builder /app /

EXPOSE 80
```

3.Make a docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

4.Make a nginx.conf

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name mydomain.com;
   root /.next/server/pages;
   index index.html;

}
```

5.Upload the created project file to the remote server

6．Start the container in the production environment

```
$ sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

7.When I check the display in the browser, CSS does not work

[image]

8.Check the view-source of index.html displayed in the browser

- Clicking the link below that is related to CSS will result in a 404 error.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
    <title>Create Next App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="5"/>
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/27d177a30947857b.css" as="style"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/27d177a30947857b.css" data-n-g=""/>
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/149b18973e5508c7.css" as="style"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/149b18973e5508c7.css" data-n-p=""/>
    <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-5cd94c89d3acac5f.js"></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-69bfa6990bb9e155.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-00b57966872fc495.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-551bef8982a15171.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-f55443f2448c8e66.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-bf8a59545a570ee7.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/vL3f544dl4bgUK74SRA_c/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/vL3f544dl4bgUK74SRA_c/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/vL3f544dl4bgUK74SRA_c/_middlewareManifest.js" defer=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="__next">
    <div class="Home_container__bCOhY">
        <main class="Home_main__nLjiQ"><h1 class="Home_title__T09hD">Welcome to <!-- --><a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>
            <p class="Home_description__41Owk">Get started by editing<!-- --> <!-- --><code class="Home_code__suPER">pages/index.js</code>
            </p>
            <div class="Home_grid__GxQ85"><a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" class="Home_card___LpL1"><h2>Documentation
                →</h2>
                <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p></a><a href="https://nextjs.org/learn"
                                                                                       class="Home_card___LpL1"><h2>
                Learn →</h2>
                <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p></a><a
                    href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples" class="Home_card___LpL1"><h2>Examples
                →</h2>
                <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p></a><a
                    href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&amp;utm_medium=default-template&amp;utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                    class="Home_card___LpL1"><h2>Deploy →</h2>
                <p>Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.</p></a></div>
        </main>
        <footer class="Home_footer____T7K"><a
                href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&amp;utm_medium=default-template&amp;utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Powered by<!-- --> <!-- --><span
                class="Home_logo__27_tb"><span
                style="box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;max-width:100%"><span
                style="box-sizing:border-box;display:block;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100%"><img
                style="display:block;max-width:100%;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"
                alt="" aria-hidden="true"
                src="data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%2772%27%20height=%2716%27/%3e"/></span><img
                alt="Vercel Logo" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
                decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic"
                style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%"/><noscript><img
                alt="Vercel Logo" srcSet="/vercel.svg 1x, /vercel.svg 2x" src="/vercel.svg" decoding="async"
                data-nimg="intrinsic"
                style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%"
                loading="lazy"/></noscript></span></span></a></footer>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{
    "props": {
        "pageProps": {}
    },
    "page": "/",
    "query": {},
    "buildId": "vL3f544dl4bgUK74SRA_c",
    "nextExport": true,
    "autoExport": true,
    "isFallback": false,
    "scriptLoader": []
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

9.Check the directory of the CSS file in the container

```
/.next/static/css # pwd
```

---

**[UPDATED]**

Like the answer posted, I change the `Dockerfile` but `CSS` doesn't work

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:1.19-alpine AS server

COPY ./etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=builder /app /
COPY --from=builder /app/public /public

EXPOSE 80
```

---

Node 16.0

Next.js 12.1

Comment: your css path has `_next` in the HTML but the folder is called `.next`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your HTML files, the static files path starts with `_next`. But your Next.js generated code has the static files in a path starting from `.next`.

You have to change your nginx configuration to fetch CSS/static files from the correct place.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   location ~ ^/_next/static/(.*)$ {
      root /.next;
      try_files "/static/$1" "/server/static/o$1" @proxy_pass;
   }
   server_name mydomain.com;
   root /.next/server/pages;
   index index.html;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing something like:

```
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
```

After your

```
RUN npm run build
```

in your Dockerfile, this should copy your assets.

In any case you might want to refer [to the offical Dockerfile example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile)

Comment: I edited the `Dockerfile` like the updated post, but the `CSS` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since Next JS uses SSR and ngix is used for static websites, you need to use the node to host the next js website. Below is my next js app docker file which works for me. Try this and let me know.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# USER nextjs

ENV PORT=80
EXPOSE 80

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```